# Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, thunk

I keep running into this error!

**Error: Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'**

I've tried every answer I could find to no avail, here is all the pertinent stuff!

**Root Reducer**

```
const createRootReducer = (history) => {
      combineReducers({
        router: connectRouter(history),
        createUser: signupReducer,
      });
    };

    export default createRootReducer;
```

**Root**

```
const Root = ({ children, initialState = {} }) => {
  const history = createBrowserHistory();
  const middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

  const store = createStore(rootReducer(history), initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{ children }</ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

**App**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Root>
        <ToastContainer hideProgressBar={true} newestOnTop={true} />
        <Navbar />
        <Landing />
        <PostList />
      </Root>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the **Signup reducer**

```
export const signupReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UserTypes.CREATE_USER_SUBMITTED:
      return {
        usernameError: "",
        passwordError: "",
        isSubmitted: true
      };
    case UserTypes.CREATE_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        usernameError: "",
        passwordError: "",
        isSubmitted: false
      };
    case UserTypes.CREATE_USER_ERROR:
        const err = {
        usernameError: "",
        passwordError: "",
        isSubmitted: false
      };
      if(action.errorData.hasOwnProperty('username')){
        err.usernameError = action.errorData['username'];
      }
      if(action.errorData.hasOwnProperty('password')){
        err.passwordError = action.errorData['password'];
      }
      return err;
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

this is the line throwing the error in the root component

```
  const store = createStore(rootReducer(history), initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your 'createRootReducer' method isn't returning anything. Is it supposed to return a function?

Comment: Yes!  It was!  That was my issue.  Thank you so much for taking the time to look!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the combined reducer.

```
const createRootReducer = (history) => {
  return combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    createUser: signupReducer,
  });
};
```

Or implicitly return using an arrow function.

```
const createRootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
  router: connectRouter(history),
  createUser: signupReducer,
});
```

Comment: Wow!  I spent hours looking for that!  Thank you so much!

I appreciate you <3

Comment: Awesome!  I went ahead and did that!  Still a stackoverflow noobie here!  

Have a great weekend my friend

Answer (score 0):

- This error comes when you initially set up the redux in your project and you do not create any reducers yet.
- so you have to Trick the Redux with Dummy Reducers. 
  for eg:

```js
export default combineReducers({ 
  test: () => 'test reducer' 
});
```

- once you create a reducer bind here 
  for eg:

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; 
import productReducer from './productReducer'

export default combineReducers({ 
  products: productReducer 
})
```